# Develop locally with IntelliJ IDE but test from remote machine

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, remote-debugging

I am working on a repository where I have to extract some features from millions of files.

For me, the current workflow is:

1. Write code in IntelliJ
2. Run unit tests
3. Dry run with small data
4. ssh to the remote machine
5. sftp the current code to the remote machine
6. Run on the server with all million of files
7. Look into the log exceptions and find out where the code is failing for edge cases
8. Fix those issues and repeat from step 1

My question would be three-fold:

- Is there an easy way how I can sync code with the remote machine automatically (I know I commit to git and then pull the changes in the machine. But is there some other way other than setting up rsync etc.?)
- Can I run code directly in the remote machine from IDE and debug it that way?

Answer (score 3):

1) There are a lot of ways to sync your code. Sometimes the best way is to create a kind of deploy script in Python or sh if you don't want to commit and push any changes you are going to test on server. You can use `sftp` or `scp` with more automation here (use `gzip` and so on). Git and rsync are more mature solutions here. But with VCS your problems will be more reproducible and easier to find.

2) You can connect to remote process to debug it directly from IntelliJ. There is a official tutorial for that: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html (but it depends on your security settings because Java debug protocol is not secured itself, you may need to setup SSH tunnel for that)

3) Another, a bit more radical option: you might run IntelliJ IDEA itself on server and debug directly. You can use Projector - an open source project which lets you run IntelliJ on the server with UI in the browser (no X11 required to run). I recommend you look at this repo firstly https://github.com/JetBrains/projector-docker or configure IntelliJ on server following instructions here: https://github.com/JetBrains/projector-server.